# What is most efficient way to convert webview to bytearray?

Tags: android, graphics, webview

I would like to get a byte array equivalent of a web screen shown on android device using `webview`.I understand that using using `capturepicture()` i can get a picture of the `webview` . And this bitmap can be transformed into bytearray. But is there a way to directly get byte array from a `webview`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but can't you just extend webview and make a method that does what you want so that you can just say `customwebviewinstance.getByteArray();

Answer (score 0):

Extend the WebView. In the `onDraw()` method, after `super.onDraw()`, extract the pixel values from the Canvas and save it. Expose this data via a getter method.